# Optimizing Canvas Draw Speed for Tower Defence Game

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am developing a tower defence game for android and have noticed a severe drop in frame rate (down to 5~10) when drawing over approximately 500 bitmaps on a canvas. I use the `View#onDraw` method to update and render the tower defence game as follows:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    game.update();
    game.render(canvas);
    this.invalidate(); //Capped to 60fps using Thread#sleep
}
```

It doesn't take very long for this many bitmaps to be drawn on the canvas as the towers fire about 10 projectiles/second. It therefore will only take 12.5 seconds to reach this number of projectiles with just 4 towers. I have seen other tower defence games such as Bloons Tower Defence which draw thousands of sprites each frame and are still able to run at 60 frames per second.

The Bitmaps are stored in a HashMap so that they don't have to be loaded to memory every frame. Apart from that common sense, I cannot seem to find any further optimizations to improve the drawing speed and subsequently the frame rate of my game.

Here is my render code for the projectiles. I have read that performing extensive transformations on the canvas' matrix can lead to poor performance, but I do not see any other way to rotate the projectiles without performing these transformations:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas, Game game){
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(Util.canvasRotate(getRotation()), x + attack.getWidth() / 2, y + attack.getHeight() / 2);
    Object resource = game.getResources().get(attack.getResource());
    if(resource instanceof Bitmap)
        canvas.drawBitmap((Bitmap)resource, null, getBounds(), null);
    else if(resource instanceof Animation)
        canvas.drawBitmap(((Animation)resource).getFrame(game.getTime()), null, getBounds(), null);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The `getRotation` method does some maths to calculate the angle:

```
float ty = centerY() - y;
float tx = centerX() - x;
float angle = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(ty, tx));
return angle;
```

Are there any faster ways of drawing Bitmaps to the canvas when there are hundreds-thousands of bitmaps? If not, are there any optimizations I could use in my render methods?

**NOTE:**
None of the Bitmaps are being resized when they are drawn - they are stored and drawn at the same resolution (projectiles=32x32 towers=72x72).

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer to your question here, note that the Stack Exchange Network has a community dedicated to game-dev-related questions, Game Development, where you may find more help. See: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mech Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you've got 500 bitmaps and you want it to run smoothly you're looking at OpenGL ES and not Canvas. See this really old Google IO video: https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, I'll have a look at that now.

Comment: Have you looked into clipping the canvas to prevent overdraw?

Comment: 500 does sound a little slow. One way to get a little more speed is to render the same bitmaps together. Also avoid save and restore as they trigger state changes can can sometimes cause major slowdowns. Use `drawBitmap (Bitmap, Matrix)` or use `Canvas.setMatrix(Matrix)` to completely replace the current transform negating the need to use save and restore. Also test your code by doing everything but the `canvas.drawBitmap` calls just in case you have a slowdown else where in your code.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the idea. I think troubleshooting it in the way you have suggested will help greatly!